# What is `this` inside a Backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning some Backbone and I'm confused as to what `this` is inside of the model.

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('hello world');
        this.bind("change:name", function() {
            console.log(this.get('name') + " is now the value for name");
        });
        this.bind('invalid', function( model, error ) {
            console.error(error);
        });
    },
    defaults: {
        name: "Bob Hope",
        height: "unknown"
    },
    validate: function ( attributes ) {
        if( attributes.name == 'Joe' ) {
            return "Uh oh, you're name is Joe!";
        }
    }
});
var person = new Person();
person.set({name: "Joe", height:"6 feet"}, {validate:true});
console.log(person.toJSON());
```

What is going on in `this.bind`? What is `change:name`? Are `initialize` and `defaults` simply just methods inside of a javascript object?

Comment: You can find all the answers on [backbonejs web site](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). Also take a look at [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-51)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside `initialize` is the instance of the model.

`.bind` is an alias for [`.on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) method inside [backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) module which allows you to bind event handlers on an object

[`change:name`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)  is just the event name, it allows you to track changes of a model's attribute named `'name'`.

[`initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) is a constructor method which will be called initially when you instantiate the model.

[`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) is an object (or it can be a function) that sets default model attributes.

So `initialize` and `defaults` are indeed methods inside an object (except that `defaults` can be also a property), but they have special meaning for backbone. And that object is extended with all other methods and properties of Backbone.Model which makes it a functional model.

read more in [backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/)