# what does "this" refer to?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What does `this` refer to in `initialize` and `render` properties?

JavaScript code:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
  initialize: function(){
    this.render(); 
  },
  render: function(){
    // Compile the template using underscore
    var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
    // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
    this.$el.html( template ); 
  }
});
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Backbone.js App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="search_container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="search_input" />
  <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this refers to the instance created by the constructor function `new SearchView`

Comment: This is based on [_What is a view?_](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-view) tutorial.

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to `console.log(this)` and see what is outputted on the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Similar and recent question: [What is `this` inside a Backbone model?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40902062/1218980) but the answer is not in depth about the context.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, it's `search_view`.

Try the following:

- add a `console.log('this in initialize', this)` into your initialize method
- add a `console.log('this in render', this)` into your render method
- add a `console.log('search_view', search_view)` after `var search_view = new SearchView(...);`

and see how those results are the same/different.